# PHP XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm trying to import a XSLT stylesheet, but still getting this error...

**PHP:**

```
//cadena original
        $xsl = new \DOMDocument();
        $xsl->load('storage/utils/cadenaoriginal_3_3.xslt');        
        // Crear el procesador XSLT que nos generará la cadena original con base en las reglas descritas en el XSLT
        $proc = new \XSLTProcessor();
        // Cargar las reglas de transformación desde el archivo XSLT.
        $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
```

**XSLT:**
url: http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cadenaoriginal_3_3/cadenaoriginal_3_3.xslt

Any idea? :(
This is the XSLT used by the goberment, so, it shouldn't have anything wrong inside, but can someone see someting weird or so?

Answer (score 6):

The stylesheet says `version="2.0"` which probably means it was written for an XSLT 2.0 processor. PHP based on libxslt supports only XSLT 1.0. In theory an XSLT 1.0 processor encountering a higher version declaration should try to switch to forwards compatible processing but I think libxslt does not do that.

So you will need to try to run the XSLT with Saxon 9 or 10, available for Java or .NET or as Saxon-C also with a PHP binding if you need to do it from PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much for that help, I'm kinda new over here, so I can´t "vote up", but it was really useful, thanks ♥